# Direct video card access

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, video

Guys, I am trying to write a class in C# that can be used as a direct replacement for the C# Bitmap class. What I want to do instead though is perform all graphic functions done on the bitmap using the power of the video card. From what I understand, functions such as DrawLine or DrawArc or DrawText are primitive functions that use simple cpu math algorithms to perform the job. I, instead, want to use the graphics card cpu and memory to do these and other advanced functions, such as skinning a bitmap (applying a texture) and true transparancy. My problem is, in C#, how do I access direct video functions? Is there a library or something I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectX or OpenGL. I prefer OpenGL, personally, especially for the level of manipulation that you're talking about.

Do you want do do this behind the scenes, or in real time (say, for a game or photo-editing program?) That may make a difference in what library you should use.

Comment: I prefer to do this behind the scenes. Is DirectX and OpenGL the only ways to go? I was hoping for something without the complexity of these libraries.

Comment: OpenGL and DirectX are pretty much the simplest ways to go about this. They wrap they slightly more complex video driver interface, which, if you're asking this question, you don't want to get into. OpenGL isn't complex at all, and their are many, many tutorials available online.

Comment: Can you do that with Open GL and DirectX?? I thought you would need something like C++ Amp or Cuda or similar to get the result back to the CPU?

Comment: @AndreasReiff CUDA and C++ are really only intended for general computation, though with CUDA/OpenGL interop you can effectively write shaders in either CL or CUDA. But, both DX and GL allow you to read anything back from the GPU that you've generated. Guys used to do general computation in OpenGL and GLSL before the other languages were available.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [DirectX](http://gregs-blog.com/2008/02/26/managed-directx-c-graphics-tutorial-1-getting-started/)?

Comment: I would prefer not to deal with the complexity of DirectX. I want to be able to call MyNewBitmapClass.DrawLine(5,10,15,20) and have it hide all those complex details

Comment: @icemanind that's exactly what you could do with DirectX put it as what happens inside your DrawLine method. Regardless you basically need to choose either DirectX or OpenGL there's no way a single person could ever hope to achieve the capabilities you need within any reasonable amount of time without those frameworks.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I guess I will brush up on my DirectX skills. Such a scary world to enter! lol